# AjaxToolkit Tab Control as Button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently building a tab control with multiple tab panels, and would like to have one of the tabs as a button instead of a template with content. The idea being that when the user clicks on the tab with the button, an event would fire and a C# method would run, and the page would post back.

How would I go about doing this? Preferably this could be something generated in the code behind as all the other tabs are programmatically generated along with the content.

Comment: Why don't you add a `Button` to that TabPanel's `ContentTemplate` and handle it's click-event?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't want the tab to display a panel, I just want an event to fire when the user clicks on that tab.

Comment: You can handle TabContainer's ActiveTabChanged event

Comment: But that event only fires when I load the tab control, not when I switch between the tabs.

Comment: As the name sugests, `ActiveTabChanged` fires when the active tab changed (switched between tabs).

Comment: Is there simply a way of making the tab header a button? I don't want the page to post back on every single tab, just the link one.

Comment: Actually it's good practise to post back as it enables to lazy load the TabPanel. You should not preload all TabPanels at the beginning (the user might want to use only one tab anyway).

Comment: This is not functionality I said I want. The tabs are not loading data from a database, so although lazy loading is nice sometimes, it is not an appropriate solution for my problem. All I need is a tab header, with an event that fires on click. Literally that is all I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle TabContainer's `ActiveTabChanged` event. Therefore you need to set `AutoPostBack` for the TabContainer to true.

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnActiveTabChanged="ActiveTabChanged">
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void ActiveTabChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex == 0)
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```